# React fetching multiple get requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Is there a simpler or more methodical way of fetching multiple requests without having to use a for loop? I basically want to fetch all the information regarding all the Kanto pokemon (151 pokemon), and then extract just the name and front sprite of the pokemon updating my state with the new populated array after fetching all 151 requests. I'm considering doing so using Promise.all but then I have no way of keeping track of the counter for every pokemon.

```
const [pokemondata,setPokemondata] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const pokemon = []
    for (let i = 1;i < 152; i++) {
      fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/${i}`)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then((data) => {
          pokemon.push({name: data.name,sprite: data.sprites.front_default})
        })
    }
    setPokemondata(pokemon)
  },[])
```

Comment: `Promise.all` returns an array of resolved promises, so there's no "counter" to keep track of, just use the array index if needed. You may want to consider also batching these requests as many browsers and APIs impose a concurrent request limit. The better option would be to select an API that returns an array of all 151 pokemons you are trying to request. Are you sure this endpoint doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of promises. I've used `Array.from()`, but you can also use a for loop and push the promises to an array. Then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all promises, and set the state when it's ready:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Demo = () => {
  const [pokemondata, setPokemondata] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all(Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, i) => // change number to 151
      fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/${i + 1}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(({ name, sprites }) => ({
          name,
          sprite: sprites.front_default    
        }))
      )).then(setPokemondata)
  },[])
  
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(pokemondata)}</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. Do you mind me asking the intuition behind not passing anything for setPokemondata, yet it is updated with the array data?

Comment: You're welcome. `setPokemondata` is a function, and then passes the data to a function, so I can skip the arrow, and pass the data directly to the set function.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could shorten it like that, good to know anyway. Thanks!